# How to add Custom Device Type for the Gutenberg Preview Option?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I found the following component and wondering how could I create a custom device type /breakpoint for Editor Preview.

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/preview-options

Then I would like to add all of these devices/breakpoints to the center of editor header [image]

Answer (score 0):

As you [already know](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/36119) (but for anyone else viewing this); this isn't yet possible without significant customization within Gutenberg; but this is being developed at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/36119